# java memory management

Tags: java, memory-management

i have the following code snapshot:

```
public void getResults( String expression, String collection ){
 ReferenceList list;
 Vector <ReferenceList> lists = new <ReferenceList> Vector();

 list = invertedIndex.get( 1 )//invertedIndex is class member

 lists.add(list);
}
```

when the method is finished, i supose that the local objects ( list, lists) are "destroyed". Can you tell if the memory occupied by list stored in invertedIndex is released as well? Or does java allocate new memory for list when assigning list = invertedIndex.get( 1 );

Comment: Note that Vector is an obsolete data strcture that should be be used anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Think of `list` and `lists` as references to objects, not the objects themselves, when working out memory management.

Before the method is called, you have `invertedIndex` marking some object. Since it is referenced from a Class (which remain in memory), that object is not available for garbage collection.

Inside the method you create a vector and use `lists` to reference it.  You also name a portion of the object inside invertedIndex with `list`.

After the method is called the two names go out of scope.  The created vector has no other reference, so it is available for garbage collection.  The object referenced by `list`, however, is still referenced indirectly by `invertedIndex`, so it is not available for garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, after the method returns, `lists` would be marked for garbage collection.

`list` and `invertedIndex` would not be affected, unless the `get` operation is destructive (IE, it removes `list` from itself and returns it).

Comment: actually i think only lists would be marked for garbage collection, since list does not allocate any memory. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, good point. Only the memory used by the `list` variable itself would be reclaimed - not any memory used by the actual object that `list` points to.